# Variable not increasing when using +=

Tags: python

I have been working on this project and I am trying to make a hunger system.
I have the remove hunger after a certain amount of time set up but when I use my "eating system" it just wont increase. I use `hunger += 50` to add but it just stays at 50...

**Here is my code if you wanna take a look**

This is the start of the loop, I'm not sure if I should have the hunger variable inside or outside of the loop...

```
def ifhealthlessthan50():

    while health >0:
        hunger = 50
```

this is the periodic hunger loss system...

```
        def hungerSystemThread():
            global hunger
            while True:
                time.sleep(65)
                hunger = hunger - 15
                print("\nYOU HAVE LOST SOME OF YOUR HUNGER\n>")
                ifhealthlessthan50()


        if hunger <= 0:
            print("YOU HAVE RUN OUT OF HUNGER AND DIED!")
            intro()
```

this is the eating system...

```
        elif choice2.lower() == 'eat':
            eatingsystem = input("WHAT WOULD YOU LIKE TO EAT?\n> ")
            if hunger <= 99:
                if eatingsystem.lower() == "apple":
                    if things['APPLE'] > 1:
                        print("eating...")
                        time.sleep(3)
                        hunger += 50
                        things['APPLE'] -= 1
                        print("ONE APPLE EATEN")
                        ifhealthlessthan50()

                elif hunger >= 100:
                    print("YOU CANNOT EAT!")
                    ifhealthlessthan50()
```

keep in mind, the `ifhealthlessthan50()` doesn't actually mean if the health is less than 50, its just the `def()` that I got too far along to change, its basically the whole loop that the entire code is in.

Comment: The bug is almost certainly due to inconsistent use of `global`, which is going to be very hard to debug without seeing the code in its entirety.  It's better to avoid using `global` entirely (*precisely* because it's extremely prone to these difficult-to-debug problems) and have another way to pass state between functions (e.g. have functions that modify the hunger explicitly return the new hunger value to the caller, or store the hunger in a specific object that's explicitly shared by the various functions).

Comment: Add code block as a whole and formatted with proper indentation.

Answer (score 1):

every time you call `ifhealthlessthan50()`, you reset the health to 50.

Even though you are increasing the hunger correctly with `hunger += 50`, you immediately set it back to 50 with the call to the function, as the while condition is true.

Perhaps you need to review your logic and clarify what you want the `while health > 0:` loop to do. If `ifhealthlessthan50()`, is your main game loop, you need not reset the value of `hunger` every time you call it.